# Setting DrawerLayout width with weights?

Tags: android, xml

Hello I am following the tutorial:

http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

There the author is using 240dp as width - that looks well on my smartphone but weird on my tablet, its to small (240dp). How can I change that code, so the width of the Drawer takes 1/2 of parent width. I thought using weights, I already tried it but it does not work

it looks like this

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3880/pimc73tc_jpg

up(smartphone)
below(tablet)

green is the menu drawer

Answer (score 1):

From android developers site [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), it is not advisable to set width to be more than 320dp:

`The drawer view specifies its width in dp units and the height matches the parent view. The drawer width should be no more than 320dp so the user can always see a portion of the main content`

Comment: but how to handle that problem with using same drawer with different devices? my tablet is 1280 x 800 , 10'' and my smartphone 1920 x 1080, 5'' - the drawer looks good on my smartphone, but on tablet it takes 1/10 full with with its 240dp

Comment: AFAIK, the best you can allocate 320dp to width. I have never seen an example where more than it has been used.

Comment: @Aanish yes, but however my 240dp width takes differenz percentage of display width away depending on tablet (portrait) and smartphone (portrait) - and there is my problem, when I put width to around 400 then it looks good on tablet.. but I dont want to create different style of drawer for different device, I want a same proportion on every device

Comment: @Steven: Did you consider using dimen.xml to use different dimensions for devices with varying screen size?

Comment: yes i am using dimen.xml but I don't want to create several main pages only of the width of the drawer. because the current layout is working good on every screen, I Just use dimen for fragments, (font size and so on) - but I want to solve this problem with weight, but i dont know how^^